# How can I make a fancy checkbox template for ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, mvc-editor-templates, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I've got a lot of `boolean`s in my model, and we're using Bootstrap, so for every boolean property I'm copy/paste refactoring:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox ">
        <input asp-for="IsFoo"/>
        <label asp-for="IsFoo"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

... but that's dumb. I tried adding this to `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/bool.cshtml`:

```
@model bool?
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox ">
        <input asp-for="@Model"/>
        <label asp-for="@ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

... and calling it with `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.IsFoo)` but all I'm getting back is a plain `input` element from the default template.

1. <strike>what am I doing wrong here</strike> *name the template 'boolean.cshtml'*
2. <strike>is `ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedValue` the right value to get the `Display(Name="xxx")` Attribute from the property</strike> *nope. `ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName`*
3. is there some new & improved version instead of Editor Templates in ASP.NET Core that I should be using (like Tag Helpers?) instead of the "old" way, and if so, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `<partial>` tag-helper:

```
<partial name="MyCheckbox" for="IsFoo" />
```

It works with binding properties too:

```
class MyModel
{
    public List<MyCheckboxModel> MyCheckboxList { get; set; }
}

class MyCheckboxModel
{
    public Boolean IsChecked { get; set; }
}

@for( Int32 i = 0; i < this.Model.MyCheckboxList.Count; i++ )
{
    <partial name="MyCheckbox" for="MyCheckboxList[i]"
}
```

Change your partial-view to:

```
@model MyCheckboxModel
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input asp-for="@Model"/>
        <label asp-for="@Model"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `for=""` attribute causes the name/id/binding context in the partial to match the named property, so ASP.NET will do the magic to ensure that `<input asp-for="@Model" />` will correspond to `Model.MyCheckBoxList[0]` and so on.

Comment: Does the Partial template have to live in a particular folder?

Comment: @ScottBaker It could be anywhere in `shared` folder or in the corresponding `Views/[ControllerName]` folder